# Which connector is correct 'by' or 'with' in the sentence?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

May I know which one is correct **by** or **with** and why?

> The model lost weight by exercising.
>
> The model lost weight with exercising.

Comment: The proof-reading questions should not be asked here. You can improve your question by explaining the source of each usage, as well as telling the reason you consider one correct and the other wrong.

Comment: @Turkan Alisoy: the guidelines state that proofreading is off-topic, ***"unless the source of concern is clearly specified"***. I would say the source of concern is very clearly specified here.

Answer (score 0):

**By** makes more sense.

When we talk about cause and effect, **by** should be used when the cause is phrased as a verb. "The model lost weight by exercising."

**With** is for when the cause is a noun, e.g. "The model lost weight with exercise."

Answer (score 0):

I agree mostly with the previous answer from Jesse.  "By" expresses a method, which can be a nominalized sentence describing an action.  That gives us a gerund expression "by exercising (strenuously)", where "exercising" is evidently a verb, since it can be modified by an adverb.  If it were a noun, the modifier would have to be an adjective like "strenuous" rather than the adverb "strenuously".

"With" expresses an instrument, which can be a noun like "exercise", and if you add a modifier to that, it has to be an adjective, like "strenuous", but it can't be an adverb.  So *"The model lost weight with exercise strenuously" is ungrammatical.

However, it's more complicated than that, because adding "-ing" to a verb can also give you a noun, as well as a gerund.  "The model lost weight by strenuous exercising" sounds okay, to me, where "exercising" is a noun (because it's modified by an adjective).  Or, perhaps more clearly, "The model lost weight by the strenuous exercising of her abdominals."

And if "exercising" can be a noun, we'd expect ?"The model lost weight with exercising" to be grammatical as well.  Yet for some reason it doesn't sound as good (I don't know why).